# Python3 how to Change Directory Back to Import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using Python 3 and I need to change my directory back to import a function from a file.
I've tried doing `from ..d import function`, but I get an error: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

```
a
├── b
|   └── c.py
├── d.py
```

Basically, I want c.py to import a function from d.py.
If it helps, I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: in `d.py` just do `from a.b.c import thing`. Make sure `__init__.py` files are in each folder

Comment: I don't want d.py to get the functions, I want c.py to import a function from d.py.

Comment: `from a.d import thing`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.path.append(path)` like:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/my/path/to/a/')

# Now just import what you want from d.py (i.e. if d has MyClass)
from d import MyClass
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My path went all the way from my C drive to the "a" file. When I import the function, the function gets underlined in red. Even doing `from d.py import function` gets underlined in red. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It worked here. I just had to use / instead of \ from windows path and everything was ok, something as `sys.path.append('C:/Users/Avell/Documents/...')`

Comment: Using sys for accessing packages in python is not practical unless there are a LOT of parent and child folders

Answer (score 0):

Try making an `__init__.py` for your directories.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: The function that I am importing gets highlighted in red. Using `from .d import function` also results in an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.d'; '__main__' is not a package`